# difference between two Get Locale language methods android

Tags: android

May i know what is the difference between `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` and `mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage()`
Sorry for my draft but i need a detailed distinction between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Returns the language name for this Locale or the empty string if no
language was set, though document states that getLanguage() returns language code but it doesn't.

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage()
```

Returns the Language code.